# Divs inside a carousel won't resize correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a row and inside of that row is a "col-md-4" and a "col-md-8". The last one resises correctly. But inside the "col-md-4" i have a bootstrap carousel which, on mobile resolution, won't resize correctly. Here's my code

HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid contactSection nopadding">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 nopadding contactDiv">
    <div id="sliderProduct" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#sliderProduct" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#sliderProduct" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-md-12 nopadding" id="contactInfo">
            <h5>Our address</h5>
            <h6><a href="https://www.google.it/maps/place/</a></h6>
            <h5>Get in touch</h5>
            <h6><a href="tel:+390255180288">Phone : +39 02 55 18 02 88</a></h6>
            <h6>Fax : +39 02 55 18 31 36</h6>
            <h6><a href="mailto:email@email.it">Email: info@ascolibottoni.it</a></h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-12 nopadding formEmail">
            <form id="contactForm" action="#">
              <h5>Name</h5>
              <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="">
              <h5>Mail</h5>
              <input name="mail" id="mail" type="email" placeholder="">
              <h5>Subject</h5>
              <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" placeholder="">
              <h5>Comment</h5>
              <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder=""></textarea>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-submit btnForm" value="Send Message" id="submit-message">
              <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#sliderProduct" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#sliderProduct" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="map" class="col-md-8 mapDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

What can i do with my css?

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong in here.

```
<h6><a href="wwwwgoogleit/maps/place/</a></h6>
```

. missing href ">.

Comment: i ve just removed it for privacy reasons. in my code the href is closed